# add event handler to Context menu Submenu in Vsto Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, vsto

```
 ProgramEngines = ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, Before:=1)
                With ProgramEngines
                    .Caption = "Program Engines"
                    With .Controls.Add(Type:=Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, Before:=1)
                        .Caption = "Gas"
                        For intCnt = 0 To colEngineData.Count - 1
                            If Strings.Split(colEngineData.Item(intCnt), "~")(0) = "Gas" Then
                                **PEG** = .Controls.Add(Type:=Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton)
                                With PEG
                                    .Caption = Strings.Split(colEngineData.Item(intCnt), "~")(1)                                   
                                    .FaceId = 548
                                End With
                            End If
                        Next
                    End With

 XCCEngines = ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, Before:=2)

                With XCCEngines
                    .Caption = "XCC Engines"

                    With .Controls.Add(Type:=Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, Before:=1)
                        .Caption = "Gas"
                        For intCnt = 0 To colEngineDataXCC.Count - 1
                            If Strings.Split(colEngineDataXCC.Item(intCnt), "~")(0) = "Gas" Then
                                **XCCG** = .Controls.Add(Type:=Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton)
                                With XCCG
                                    .Caption = Strings.Split(colEngineDataXCC.Item(intCnt), "~")(1)                                   
                                    .FaceId = 548
                                End With
                            End If
                        Next
                    End With


        Private Sub ButtonClick(ByVal ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles PEG.Click, XCCG.Click
            PutValue_Engine_Trans(ctrl.Caption)
        End Sub
```

I have build a context menu with sub menu(PEG,XCCG) and i have attached the event handler for submenu.But when I run the code event is firing for only first Event PEG
Please Help me in this . I am new to VSTO.

Comment: Hi Please Help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question I posted here : 
[Respond to Multiple VSTO Context Menus in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557192/respond-to-multiple-vsto-context-menus-in-vb-net/46568781#46568781)

after  these 2 lines...

```
 **XCCG** = .Controls.Add(Type:=Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton)

 **PEG** = .Controls.Add(Type:=Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton)
```

add a line that looks like this

```
AddHandler XCCG.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick

AddHandler PEG.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
```

That did the trick for me. 
Here is an example of my Event Handler,  I am simply using the Caption to determine which menu was clicked. In my case , that is good enough.

```
Private Sub cb_Click(Ctrl As CommandBarButton, ByRef CancelDefault As Boolean) Handles cb.Click
        MsgBox(Ctrl.Caption, MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal, "Fast View")
    End Sub
```