# Respond to Multiple VSTO Context Menus in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, vsto

Trying to build a VSTO w/ VB.Net. 
I did ask, it has to be VB.Net.

Application Level ADDIN targeted at EXCEL

My challenge is trying to build a context menu that has an indeterminate number of children.

I can make the Menu, but I currently only get the onClick to fire for the last button.

I have researched this quite thoroughly and I can not find a VB example. There are plenty examples in VB of adding a simple context menu.

There are examples in C#, but you do something like this

```
 cb.Click += cbButton_Clicked;
```

I have yet to figure out how to do that in VB, hence the question. 
The entirety of the code is below. I can click on any of the first 5 buttons, and nothing happens. When I click on the last one, it fires a message box as expected.

I will have an indeterminate number of menu items, so I can  not just add  X #  handlers.

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
 Dim WithEvents cb As CommandBarButton
    Dim TradeName As String = "MyMenu"
    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

        ' AddHandler Application.WorkbookBeforeSave, AddressOf Application_WorkbookBeforeSave

        AddHandler Application.NewWorkbook, AddressOf ThisWorkbook_NewWorkbook

    End Sub


    Private Sub ThisWorkbook_NewWorkbook(wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)

        AddMenu2()
    End Sub



    Public Function GetCellContextMenu() As Office.CommandBar

        Return Application.CommandBars("Cell")
    End Function


    Public Sub AddMenu2()
        Dim Bar As Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBar
        Dim NewControl As Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarControl

        Try

            Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(TradeName).Delete()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


        Bar = Application.CommandBars("Cell")
        NewControl = Bar.Controls.Add(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, Id:=1, Temporary:=True)

        With NewControl
            .Caption = TradeName
            .BeginGroup = True
            .TooltipText = TradeName & " Queries."
        End With

        Dim ag As New fvConnectionSuperAg
        Dim l As List(Of fvConnection) = ag.Items

        For Each conn As fvConnection In l

            cb = NewControl.Controls.Add(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoControlType.msoControlButton)
            With cb
                .Caption = conn.Name.Value
                .FaceId = 218
                   ' HERE IS WHERE  I THINK I SHOULD CONNECT THE HANDLER 
            End With
```

Next

```
    End Sub

    Private Sub cb_Click(Ctrl As CommandBarButton, ByRef CancelDefault As Boolean) Handles cb.Click
        MsgBox(Ctrl.Caption, MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal, "Fast View")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Never fails, posting on SO makes you clarify the question in your head , which often leads to an answer ....

I found the answer in this article that discusses adding event handlers programatically. Not related to VSTO really at all.

http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/EventHandler.aspx

here is the excerpt from previous posting 
the difference s the **ADDHANDLER** call right after creating the button.

```
 cb = NewControl.Controls.Add (Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoControlType.msoControlButton)
            AddHandler cb.Click, AddressOf cb_Click
            With cb
                .Caption = conn.Name.Value
                .FaceId 
            End With
```